# xlwings.App() Creates an Excel instance with no loaded plugins

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to work with Python, Excel and CapIQ.  If I start my excel instance normally and then connect to it using xlwings everything works properly, but if I try to create an excel instance using python no plugins are loaded.

Is this some kind of problem on my end or is this expected behavior?

The current situation is a bit inconvenient since I must have an excel instance running before I can start any Python programs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is expected. When you start Excel programmatically, it will not load any add-ins, you will have to do that manually.

If it's a standard `xlam` add-in, you just need to do `xw.Book(r'C:\path\to\addin.xlam')`. If it's an xll, then see the [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125610/xlwings-wipes-out-my-excel-addin):

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('YourWorkbook.xls')
wb.app.api.RegisterXLL(r"C:\path\to\YourAddIn.xll")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately the CIQ plugin seems to be problematic - it is actually composed of a dll, xll, and udf.  The questions I have found that specifically involve loading CIQ into a programically created Excel instance all end in failure: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ce7fa693-2be4-414d-b725-a4c5aabff1d3/calling-excel-udf-from-c?forum=exceldev https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439142/calling-excel-udf-from-net

Comment: You should be able to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa141014(v=office.10)). Use `wb.app.api.AddIns(strAddInName)` and `wb.app.api.AddIns.Add(strFilePath)` instead of `Excel....`